# Get specific div with class of selector stored in variable jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I am using a variable to replace a jQuery selector like so:

```
var $someDiv = $('.some-div');
```

And I had a series of divs with that class name:

```
<div class='some-div'></div>
<div class='some-div'></div>
<div class='some-div'></div>
```

If one of those were to have an additional class, say `.additional-class`, how might I select it using the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector) and pass additional class as `selector`

> A string containing a selector expression to match the current set of elements against.

```
$someDiv.filter('.additional-class')
```

```js
var $someDiv = $('.some-div');
$someDiv.filter('.additional-class').css('background-color', 'green')
```

```css
.some-div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin : 10px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='some-div'></div>
<div class='some-div additional-class'></div>
<div class='some-div'></div>
```